# HP 625 Overheating Problem

Tags: windows-7, laptop, fan, cooling

I just got a new HP 625 with a Turion dual core at 2.5 GHz, 2 GB DDR3 RAM and a ATI 4200 HD videocard, but after using it I think I may be experiencing a problem with it's cooling system.

I watch the temps with `speedfan` and the laptop is usually between 45 and 55 C degrees, but after moderate use, the fan won't cool anymore and the laptop goes up to 70 C degrees. That's when the fan won't work at all, only cooling for about 10-20 seconds at full speed and then completely stopping.

I also noticed the laptop won't really cool that good while I'm using it and the temperature constantly goes up.

Could I be dealing with a faulty system or just plain bad settings? I'm using Windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: Where did you get it? If it's new, return it because it's obviously a hardware defect and demand a new model.

Answer (score 0):

It's regular bad settings, laptops are made to be quiet, therefore the fan noise has to be cut off until it reaches a temperature. My Laptop reaches 90c sometimes, although that's because of the Core i7 CPU.

But also make sure you aren't placing it on a bed or something that will block airflow from the vent. This will make your laptop heat up, even putting it on your lap will make it heat up. A desk/table is the only place it will be able to vent air properly.